# мы создаем нового пользователя в социальной сети. Какой статус код нужно вернуть?

Tags: python, http, requests

мы создаем нового пользователя в социальной сети. Какой статус код нужно вернуть?

1. 200
2. 404
3. 500
4. 201

Comment: Ну очевидно либо 200, либо 201, а что? :)

Answer (score 1):

Этот код `201` состояния должен быть возвращен, если пользователь успешно создан. Это указывает на то, что сервер выполнил запрос и создал новый ресурс.